# How properly check boolean value in freemarker

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean, freemarker

So, I'am trying to make simple condition:

```
<#if documentData.isOtherInsurance>
<p>&#10004 Да</p>
<#else> <p>&#10008;Нет </p></#if>
```

and I'm getting mistake like:

```
For "#if" condition: Expected a boolean, but this has evaluated to a method+sequence (wrapper: f.e.b.SimpleMethodModel):
==> documentData.isOtherInsurance!false  [in template "InsuranceNotification" at line 1, column 1445]

----
Tip: Maybe using obj.something instead of obj.isSomething will yield the desired value.
----

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: #if documentData.isOtherInsurance!false  [in template "InsuranceNotification" at line 1, column 1440]
----
```

So I tried almost everything

1)

```
<#if ${documentData.isOtherInsurance>} <p>&#10004 Да</p> ...
```

```
Syntax error in template "InsuranceNotification" in line 1, column 1445:
You can't use ${...} (an interpolation) here as you are already in FreeMarker-expression-mode. Thus, instead of ${myExpression}, just write myExpression. (${...} is only used where otherwise static text is expected, i.e., outside FreeMarker tags and interpolations, or inside string literals.)
```

Comment: Did you try what it suggested?

Answer (score 1):

`isOtherInsurance` is a method, as the error messages says, not a `boolean`. Try `documentData.otherInsurance` (no "is"), which is the Java Bean property that the `boolean isOtherInsurance()` Java method automatically defines.

Note that sometimes developers incorrectly declare such methods as `Boolean isOtherInsurance()` (with capital `Boolean`). Then they should change that to `Boolean getOtherInsurance()`, or to `boolean isOtherInsurance()`. But if they won't, you can still use `documentData.isOtherInsurance()` (note that `()` which will call the method, so then then the return value of the method will be used, instead of the method itself).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<#if documentData.isOtherInsurance> 
    <@displayRow label="isOtherInsurance" value="&#10004 Да" />
<#else>
    <@displayRow label="isOtherInsurance" value="&#10008;Нет" />
</#if>
```